# convert mvc objects to csla.net 2.1

Tags: model-view-controller

How to convert/map MVC objects to CSLA.net 2.1 and potential issues? Please help me. Thanks.
MVC Object means Model in MVC.

Comment: What do you mean by MVC object?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a way to map MVC models (POCO) to a CSLA Entity?

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))